# Read Spark streaming source once when applying and writing multiple transformations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use Spark Structured Streaming to achieve the following flow:

```
                                        ┌──────────────────────┐
                                    ┌──►│Transformation DF (1) ├──┐
                                    │   └──────────────────────┘  │
┌──────────────────┐   ┌─────────┬──┘                             └──►┌────────────────┐
│Source Kafka Topic├──►│Source DF│                                    │Sink Kafka Topic│
└──────────────────┘   └─────────┴──┐                             ┌──►└────────────────┘
                                    │   ┌──────────────────────┐  │
                                    └──►│Transformation DF (2) ├──┘
                                        └──────────────────────┘
```

What actually happens is the following:

```
                         ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────────────┐
                      ┌─►│Source DF (1) ├───►│Transformation DF (1) ├──┐
                      │  └──────────────┘    └──────────────────────┘  │
┌──────────────────┬──┘                                                └──►┌────────────────┐
│Source Kafka Topic│                                                       │Sink Kafka Topic│
└──────────────────┴──┐                                                ┌──►└────────────────┘
                      │  ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────────────┐  │
                      └─►│Source DF (2) ├───►│Transformation DF (2) ├──┘
                         └──────────────┘    └──────────────────────┘
```

The logic runs as expected, the only issue is that Spark initializes two different streaming queries that are reading the same exact messages from the source topic.

This creates a huge load on the source kafka topic, especially when running hundreds of different transformations. Since transformations are lazily evaluated, It seems like I don't have any control over this behavior.

The code roughly looks like the following:

```py
    source_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")...
    # each transformation is using different values for select/filter/window/watermark/group by
    # therefore the transformations can't be merged into a single dataframe
    source_df.filter(some_conditions).writeStream.format("kafka")...
    source_df.filter(some_other_conditions).writeStream.format("kafka")...
```

Is there any way to overcome this behavior or is it intentional by design for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Using foreachBatch you can achieve it. foreachBatch performs custom write logic on each micro-batch. This way spark will not initializes two different streaming queries.

You can do this way,

```
source_df
  .writeStream
  .foreachBatch { (batch: DataFrame, _: Long) =>
    
    batch.filter(some_conditions).write.format("kafka")...
    batch.filter(some_other_conditions).write.format("kafka")...

  }
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with window aggregations. To run window aggregation on a stream I must use writeStream, otherwise Spark doesn't store the intermediate state of the aggregation between micro-batches and it just writes the aggregated windows of the current micro-batch to the sink.

Comment: Can you share code snippet with windows aggregation.

Comment: `df.select("timestamp", "bytes_sent").withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minute").groupBy(sql_func.window("timestamp", "1 minute")).agg(sql_func.sum("bytes_sent"))`

Answer (score 0):

Using cache should avoid recomputing of DF although it would still lead to two queries.

```
source_df.cache()
```